# How to upgrade the CUDA version in a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, build, cuda, upgrade

Earlier I installed `CUDA 9.2` on my machine and built a solution with it. Then I upgraded `Visual Studio 2017` to a revision that is not supported by `CUDA 9.2`, so I'm getting errors like:

```
1>D:\Dev\Views\Engines\ProbQA\ProbQA\PqaCore>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=\"sm_61,compute_61\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true -ID:\Dev\Views\Engines\ProbQA\ProbQA\PqaCore\ -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" --source-in-ptx -G -lineinfo  --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=32  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -D_DEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_USRDLL -DPQACORE_EXPORTS -D_WINDLL -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W4 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd /GR" -o x64\Debug\CudaEngineGpu.cu.obj "D:\Dev\Views\Engines\ProbQA\ProbQA\PqaCore\CudaEngineGpu.cu"
1>c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v9.2\include\crt/host_config.h(133): fatal error C1189: #error:  -- unsupported Microsoft Visual Studio version! Only the versions 2012, 2013, 2015 and 2017 are supported!
1>CUDACOMPILE : nvcc warning : '--device-debug (-G)' overrides '--generate-line-info (-lineinfo)'
1>CudaEngineGpu.cu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 9.2.targets(707,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=\"sm_61,compute_61\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu -rdc=true -ID:\Dev\Views\Engines\ProbQA\ProbQA\PqaCore\ -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\include" --source-in-ptx -G -lineinfo  --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=32  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -D_DEBUG -D_WINDOWS -D_USRDLL -DPQACORE_EXPORTS -D_WINDLL -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W4 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd /GR" -o x64\Debug\CudaEngineGpu.cu.obj "D:\Dev\Views\Engines\ProbQA\ProbQA\PqaCore\CudaEngineGpu.cu"" exited with code 2.
```

I've installed `CUDA 10.0` that claims to be compatible with `VS2017 Update 8` and any later versions. However, my solution still uses `CUDA 9.2`.

How to upgrade the solution to `CUDA 10.0`? Can I do this from GUI somewhere, or do I have to edit project files and something else?

Comment: Have you tried `Build Dependencies" -> "Build Customizations"? Or you can do it manually by opening the `vcxproj` file associated to your solution and then changing `9.2` to `10.0`.

Comment: @JackOLantern, thanks, that works! You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two ways to upgrade the CUDA version in a Visual Studio solution:

1. `Build dependencies` -> `Build customizations`;
2. Open the `vcxproj` file associated to the Visual Studio solution and change `9.2` to `10.0` wherever `9.2` occurs.